# Authenticate with Google Plus, with android App, how to get REFRESH TOKEN

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, google-oauth

Im triying to authenticate with google, I´m currently using the way i´t is recomended on his documentation, but.. is there any EASY way to get the refresh token?, I make the auth and get the token, but it have been impossible for me to take the refresh token , and I need id.

I have tried lots of ways, I have spend more than a week with this issue, is it possible to get that token?  I´ve tried with lots of manuals, tutorials... but I can´t.

Anyone Knows any place where I can Know how to get the resfresh_token and it is good explained and that is currently working?.

Thanks a lot!!

Pd: is a native android App.

EDIT:
Ok, for More info, I´m making the auth as is in google´s documentation to auth with GoogleApiClient with little variations( because I´m using it as a cain of manager) . THIS PART RUN´S OK:

Firs instead of calling on create I call:

```
public void logginGooglePlus(GooglePlusAuthCallback googlePlusAuthCallback) {
    gPAuthCallback = googlePlusAuthCallback;
    // Initializing google plus api client
    String scope = "audience:server:client_id:" + SERVER_CLIENT_ID;
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    mSignInClicked = true;
    signInWithGplus(gPAuthCallback);
}
```

I continue just with copy&paste with the google´s:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(),
        // this,
        // 0).show();
        if (gPAuthCallback != null) {
            gPAuthCallback.onLoginError(result.toString());
        }
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
        Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
        }
        mIntentInProgress = false;
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    } 
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    mSignInClicked = false;

    // Get user's information
    if (gPAuthCallback != null) {
        gPAuthCallback.onLoginSuccesful();
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

/**
 * Sign-in into google
 * */
public void signInWithGplus(GooglePlusAuthCallback googlePlusAuthCallback) {
    gPAuthCallback = googlePlusAuthCallback;
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}

/**
 * Method to resolve any signin errors
 * */
private void resolveSignInError() {
    if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally I call to get the persons data:

```
public void getProfileInformation(
        GooglePlusGetPersonCallback getPersonCallback) {
    this.googlePlusGetPersonCallback = getPersonCallback;
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e("GPlus", "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            new getTokenAsyncTask().execute();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (googlePlusGetPersonCallback != null) {
            // googlePlusGetPersonCallback.ongeGooglePersonError(e.getCause()
            // .toString());
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ok, leaving here is easy, now It starts the funny part: I need the Refresh Token because I have to sign in with a server, and I have to pass the access_token, refresh_token and user_id.

reading this: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth

I understand that I have to make the getToken call with a different Scope, so I change it: the method for get token is :

```
    // GET TOKEN 2o plano
public class getTokenAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            String acountname = Plus.AccountApi
                    .getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            // agregamos el scope del server para que me loguee para la app
            // "crossclient"
            String serverScope = "audience:server:client_id:"
                    + SERVER_CLIENT_ID;

            String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(GooglePlusManager.this,
                    acountname, serverScope);


            return token;

        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            // startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), "NECESITA AUT");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // TODO: handle the exception
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String code) {
        String token = code;
        if (googlePlusGetPersonCallback != null) {
            googlePlusGetPersonCallback.ongeGooglePersonSuccesful(
                    currentPerson, token);
        }

    }
}
```

According to documentation, with this I´ll get a token that: "The ID token will contain several data fields", and I´m only retrieving a string token ( but it does not give any crash or issue so I suppose it is Ok). I haven´t got access to the Server, but I´ve suppose that it is ok, because the ios app is running ok already ( another company have done it in Ios), do I have to ask them to make in the server any thing so I can authenticate my android app with the server?

The ios app is passing to the server the parameter I´ve already said (acces, refres, id) So I Imagine that I have to pass the same in android, I have acces to the console and I have declared the android app in the same project.

well, from the part I am, that I have an supposed valid token.. how can I get the refresh token? I´m completely lost...

If anyone knows how to get it.. I´ll invite as much beer as you can ( I have lost so many hours with this :S ).

xcuses for the really really big post :( ( it´s my first one!).

Comment: It would probably be helpful for you to show the code which is not working

Answer (score 0):

According to [the google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) you can exchange tokens.

So, if you post required parameters to below link, then you will obtain a refresh token

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
```

Parameters,

```
var params = {
    code: 'FROM ANDROID [ONE TIME CODE]',
    client_id: 'FROM YOUR GOOGLE CONSOLE',
    client_secret: 'FROM YOUR GOOGLE CONSOLE',
    redirect_uri: 'FROM YOUR GOOGLE CONSOLE',
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
    access_type:'offline'
};
```

The only thing you must send from android is *one-time code*. Other parameters are static, store they in a config file.

```
var params = {
    code: 'FROM ANDROID [ONE TIME CODE]',
```

Android side, [Enable server-side API access for your app](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in), after implementing this, you will have an *one-time code*

I hope these will be helpful for you.